How to evaluate this Ahmed-like integral $ \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{7\pi^2}{96}$
How to evaluate that : $$ \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{7}{96}\pi^2 $$
I'm trying to convert it into a double integral.  Notice :
$$ \left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\right)\right]'=\frac{2-x^2}{y^2-x^2+2}$$
So,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 &\frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx  \\
    &= \int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_0^1\frac{2-x^2}{y^2-x^2+2}dy\right)dx  \\
    &= \frac{\pi^2}{8}-\iint_{[0, 1]\times[0,1]}\frac{2-x^2}{y^2-x^2+2}dydx
\end{align*}
But I can't evaluate it anymore. So I try the second method:
\begin{align*}
I(\alpha) 
    &= \int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\alpha(2-x^2)}}{1+x^2}dx  \text{, }\\
I(1) &=\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx \text{, and} \\
I(+\infty) &=\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
I(\infty)-I(1)
    &= \int_1^{\infty}\frac{d}{d\alpha}I(\alpha)dx  \\
    &= \int_1^{\infty}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{(1+x^2)(1+2\alpha^2-\alpha^2x^2)}dx d\alpha  \\
    &=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{3-\alpha^2}{\alpha^4}\int_0^1 \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{x^2-(1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2})}}-\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}} d\alpha
\end{align*}
I can evaluate
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{J}
    &= \int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx  \\
    &=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}-\frac14 \right)\pi \text{, }
\end{align*}
but I can't evaluate
\begin{align*}
\color{red}{K} &= \int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{x^2-(1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2})}  \\
I(1) &= \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx \\
    &= \frac{\pi^2}{8}+\color{green}{(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}-\frac14)\pi\int_1^{\infty}\frac{3-\alpha^2}{\alpha^4}d\alpha}-\int_1^{\infty}\frac{3-\alpha^2}{\alpha^4}K(\alpha)d\alpha  \text{, }
\end{align*}
and we know
$$  \color{green}{P}=0  \text{.}  $$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
I(1) &= \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx  \\
    &= \frac{\pi^2}{8}-\int_1^{\infty}\frac{3-\alpha^2}{\alpha^4}K(\alpha)d\alpha \text{, }
\end{align*}
which I can't evaluate; again, I failed.
Could anybody please give me some hints or answers?

Remark: You don't need to enclose text in $..$, it just looks a little sloppy. If you must, please use $\text{foo bar}$ instead to render, e.g., $\text{foo bar}$.

One assumes you have read the solution for Ahmed's integral as a (possible) model for a solution to this problem?  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270329763_Definitely_an_Integral_10884

Uh, for the record, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5169.

See here (particularly Jack's hinted method) for the same integral, but evaluated over $[0,1/\sqrt3]$.

$$K := \int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{x^2-(1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2})} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
I'll simplify things by letting $\beta^2 = 1 + \frac{1}{\alpha^2}$:
$$K := \int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{x^2-\beta^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
The numerator begs for trig sub:
$$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\begin{align*}
x &= \sqrt 2 \sin \theta \\
\dd x &= \sqrt 2 \cos \theta\, \dd \theta \\
\sqrt{2-x^2} &= \sqrt{ 2 - 2 \sin^2 \theta } \\
&= \sqrt {2} \left| \cos \theta \right| \\
&= \sqrt {2} \cos \theta
\end{align*}$$
Then
$$
K = \sqrt 2 \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{2 \cos^2 \theta}{2 \sin^2 \theta - \beta^2}  \, \dd \theta
$$
We'll let, again for notational pleasantry, $\sqrt 2 \gamma = \beta$, so we can cancel out that $2$:
$$
K = \sqrt 2 \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{ \cos^2 \theta}{  \sin^2 \theta - \gamma^2}  \, \dd \theta
$$
Apply Weierstrass substitution:
$$\begin{align*}
t &:= \tan \frac \theta 2 \\
\sin \theta &= \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \\
\cos \theta &= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \\
\dd \theta &= \frac{2}{1+t^2} \, \dd t
\end{align*}$$
Then
$$
K = \sqrt 2 \int_0^{\sqrt {2} - 1} \frac{\displaystyle \left( \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \right)^2}{\displaystyle \left( \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \right)^2 - \gamma^2} \, \frac{2}{1+t^2} \, \dd t
$$
Simplify and do a partial fraction decomposition. You'll get to
$$
\begin{align}
K &= \sqrt 2 \frac{\gamma^2-1}{\gamma} \int_0^{\sqrt {2} - 1}  \frac{1}{ \gamma t^2 - 2 t + \gamma } \, \dd t \\
&\quad + \sqrt 2 \frac{\gamma^2-1}{\gamma} \int_0^{\sqrt {2} - 1}   \frac{1}{ \gamma t^2 + 2 t  + \gamma}  \, \dd t
\\ &\quad + 2\sqrt 2 \int_0^{\sqrt {2} - 1} \frac{1}{t^2 + 1} \, \dd t
\end{align}
$$
What remains from here is fairly trivial.

tks，i found a better way to solve it.

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx \\
=& \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{2-x^2}}{(1+x^2)[1+(2-x^2)y^2]} dy\ dx\\
 =& \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+3y^2) \sqrt{2-x^2}}\bigg(\frac{3}{1+x^2} -\frac1{1+(2-x^2)y^2}\bigg)dx\ dy\\
 =& \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{1+3y^2}\bigg(\frac\pi{\sqrt3}-\frac{\frac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{1+2y^2}}{\sqrt{1+2y^2}}\bigg)dy\\
=& \ \frac{\pi^2}{36}+\int_0^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{1+2x^2}}{(1+3x^2)\sqrt{1+2x^2}} dy \\
=& \ \frac{\pi^2}{36}- \int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\sqrt{1+2x^2}\ d\bigg(\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1+2x^2}}x \bigg)\\
 \overset{ibp}=& \ \frac{\pi^2}{24}+\int_0^1 \frac{x\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}} x}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{2x^2+1}} \ dx
= \frac{\pi^2}{24}+\frac{\pi^2}{32}=\frac{7\pi^2}{96}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{x\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}} x}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{2x^2+1}} \ dx\\
 =& \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2 }{(x^2+1)(x^2+y^2 +2x^2y^2 )} \ dy \ dx\\
 =& \ \frac12\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \bigg( \frac{x^2 }{x^2+1}+\frac{y^2}{y^2+1} \bigg)\frac1{x^2+y^2 +2x^2y^2 }\ dy \ dx\\
 =& \ \frac12\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}dxdy=\frac{\pi^2}{32}
\end{align}

Nice utilisation of the symmetry +1

for $0\leq u\leq \sqrt{2}$, let,
\begin{align}\psi(u)=\int_0^u\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2-x^2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx\end{align}
\begin{align}\psi(u)&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\arctan\left(\sqrt{2-u^2}\right)\arctan u+\int_0^u\frac{x\arctan x}{(3-x^2)\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx\\
&\overset{z=\sqrt{2-x^2}}=\arctan\left(\sqrt{2-u^2}\right)\arctan u-\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2-u^2}}\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2-z^2}\right)}{1+z^2}dz\\
&=\arctan\left(\sqrt{2-u^2}\right)\arctan u-\psi\left(\sqrt{2-u^2}\right)+\psi\left(\sqrt{2}\right)
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\boxed{\psi(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{32}+\frac{\psi\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}}\end{align}
\begin{align}\psi\left(\sqrt{2}\right)&\overset{u=\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}}=\sqrt{2}\int_0^1\frac{u\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}u\right)}{(3-2u^2)\sqrt{1-u^2}}du\end{align}
For $a\in [0,\sqrt{2}]$ define,
\begin{align}F(a)&=\sqrt{2}\int_0^1\frac{u\arctan\left(au\right)}{(3-2u^2)\sqrt{1-u^2}}du\\
F^\prime(a)&=\sqrt{2}\int_0^1\frac{u^2}{(3-2u^2)(1+a^2u^2)\sqrt{1-u^2}}du\\
&=\sqrt{2}\left[\frac{\sqrt{3}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{3(1-u^2)}}\right)}{2+3a^2}-\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{u\sqrt{1+a^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right)}{(2+3a^2)\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{\pi\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}{2+3a^2}-\frac{\pi}{(2+3a^2)\sqrt{2(1+a^2)}}\\
F(\sqrt{2})&=\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}{2+3a^2}-\frac{\pi}{(2+3a^2)\sqrt{2(1+a^2)}}\right)da\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left[\arctan\left(a\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2(1+a^2)}}\right)\right]_0^{\sqrt{2}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)=\boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{12}}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\boxed{\psi\left(\sqrt{2}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{12},\psi(1)=\frac{7\pi^2}{96}}\end{align}
NB:
The computation of $\psi\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$ is not necessary to compute $\psi(1)$, the change of variable $u=\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ can be performed directly, but one obtains a nice result.
